# getting error message when trying to import a newly installed python package

Tags: python, installation, package

I just downloaded a python package and installed it on a Linux box using the following command:

```
python setup.py install --prefix=/home/ubuntu/dev/git/nx
```

That is, I did not use the default install directory. I then appended the existing `PYTHONPATH` variable in `~/.bashrc` as follows:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/some/previous/path:/home/ubuntu/dev/git/nx
```

But when I run `import` of the package in python, I get a `ImportError: No module named` error.

Am I specifying the wrong path in `PYTHONPATH`? If so, how do I figure out which path to put there? Or is there a different error?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ran

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

Didn't have to mess with `PYTHONPATH`. Working great!

Answer (score 0):

If you put it in bashrc you will either need to source ~/.bashrc or log in again. Depending on your distro, bashrc might not be the right place to put it. You're using Ubuntu, so it will work.

It's also generally good practice to include the current variable when exporting a path-type variable.

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/home/ubuntu/dev/git/nx
```

You can verify that your path is correct with echo $PYTHONPATH. You can also run the above command to see if it will fix it (albeit temporarily and only in your current shell).

Comment: I did run source and check $PYTHONPATH before posting my question. My guess is that I need to specify some subdirectory under `/home/ubuntu/dev/git/nx` in `PYTHONPATH` but I don't know how to figure that out.